# How to division vector by scalar in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a parquet file which contain two columns (id,features).I want to subtract features from scalar , divide output by another scalar and save output as parquet file.

```
    val df=sqlContext.read.parquet("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/model/data/user/part-r-00000-7d55ba81-5761-4e36-b488-7e6214df2a68.snappy.parquet").toDF("id","features") 
 val constant1 = 2.4848911616270923 
val constant2 = 1.8305483113586494
 val performComputation = (s: Double, val1: Double, val2: Double) => { Vectors.dense((s - val1) / val2) 
df.withColumn("features", ((df("features")-val1)/val2)) } df.write.parquet("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/output1")
```

parquet file stile the same.what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the same dataframe you have read.
Try smth like:

```
val result = df.withColumn("features", ((df("features") - val1) / val2))
result.write.parquet("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/output1")
```

Comment: ok,when writting val result = df.withColumn("features", ((df("features") - val1) / val2)) inside } of dense not give me any result.

Comment: Try to register performComputation function as UDF and use it like df.withColumn("features", performComputationUDF(df("features")))